# Sanity check: Is water a good thermal insulator?

Tags: water, thermal-conductivity

Last week, we had a few exceptionally cold days that froze a lot of ponds and rivers. On a hike through the forest, I broke through a weak spot in the ice, and soaked my boots with ice-cold water. I rushed to a snow covered spot (because snow is a good thermal insulator) and removed my boots to pour out the water and wring out my socks to get as much cold water out of them before putting them back on.

The socks felt kinda cold at first, but I knew that it wouldn't take long before the cold water in my socks, combined with the freezing temperatures would start freezing off my feet with a lot of pain.

To my surprise, this never happened. After half an hour walking through ice, snow and semi-frozen mud, my socks still felt wet but comfortably warm...?

Later that day I told my dad about this experience. I assumed that it was because my boots were surprisingly well insulated. He said that it was more likely due to the fact that water is a very good insulator.
Huh??? Water? A good insulator??
He explained that back in the days, when they had to harvest Brussels' Sprouts in winter (for those of you that don't know: these were/are harvested by hand) they experienced similar effects: when their gloves were new, the plastic outer layer would still be waterproof. Their hands would get very cold when wearing these in freezing temperatures. However, when the gloves were already a little worn down and the outer layer was punctured here and there, water would seep into the inner layer and their hands would be comfortably warm.

This anecdote shocked me... It goes against everything I ever knew about water and its thermal conductivity.
I've always considered water a very GOOD thermal conductor, and thus a BAD insulator.

I would be rather quick to reject this theory, but still... I experienced the same thing with my boots?

I also Googled the thermal conductivity of water, and... to my surprise it is indeed rather low?
0.5918 W·m−1·K−1. Somewhere in between Marble and Teflon.

So... is water indeed a good thermal insulator? And if yes, how come I have always known it as a good thermal conductor?
If no, how do you explain the effects I experienced in my boots, and the farmers experienced in their winter gloves?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermal_conductivities That is for stagnant water.

Comment: In practice, like in your boot, thermal conduction is not the primary mechanism of heat exchange for water.  Instead, most heat exchange is through advection (that is, the motion of the water itself, either by thermal convection, or just sloshing around in your boot).

Comment: I'm pretty sure both of you were experiencing how wetsuits keep you warm. A good, thin thermal conductor water layer between your body and a poor conductor(insulator) boot/neoprene/glove. I don't know the proper thermodynamics to detail it into an answer hopefully someone will

Comment: @JKusin: I don't think water is an aid to a wet suit keeping one warm, it's just not a huge hindrance. Wet suits are only wet because they are sufficient and cheaper and easier to maintain than dry suits, which are much warmer.

Comment: Ya if you can do without the water that's better. But I'd say a full layer of semi-trapped water is better than a few damp areas. The damp areas will evaporate and cool and possibly freeze. A full submersing, while not better than no water at all, is better than a little water in certain situations. I guess this is kind of a separate phenomenon though.

Comment: @JKusin I'm talking about actual warmth. Warmer than no moisture at all.

Answer (score 1):

The thermal conductivity of the water in your boot is not relevant because the water is sloshing around, and therefore there isn't a linear temperature gradient.  Most of the heat transfer to the outside through the water will instead be through advection (ie, the moving around of the water) or flow of water in and out of your boot (which is the worst).

A trick if you're out on a cold day and your foot gets really wet, is to put a plastic bag over your sock and inside your boot.  (experimental evidence: I still have ten toes.)  What does this do then?

The main two things it does are: 1) it helps your toes not be isolated -- usually people lose toes to frostbite, not their whole foot, which generally has sufficient blood flow (but it probably also increases ones chance of hypothermia); 2) it stops water from flowing in and out, and that flowing water would take *a lot* of energy to heat up again and again (even if it's just a bit of melted snow with each step).

Overall, I don't think this says much about the quality of your boot, other than it doesn't have huge holes in it to allow for the free-flow of water.

For example, in kayaking people often use "dry tops" that make rubber seals around the neck and wrists (and are made from thin waterproof material so they don't provide much insulation on the outside).  A good dry top that truly keeps you dry is a total pleasure, and you can finish an entire day of freezing cold water and be dry and comfortable.  But a poor dry top works well enough too, so long as not much water flows in and out.  Without a drytop, you'd probably be dead in 20 minutes in the usual water where one would wear a dry top.

So what are the quantifications of water that relate to advection?  Honestly, I'm not totally sure, but I would guess heat capacity and viscosity.  That is, how well does the water flow between your foot and your boot, and how much heat does it take with it when it does?